# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit. .Rhistory

Tags: git

I just selected some files to commit and when I want to push:

! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://....git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

when I give git status the following is shown:
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
(use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Untracked files:
(use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

```
.Rhistory
```

I don't see any conflict but this .Rhistory which I don't know what it is.

I am very thankful for any advice

Comment: `You may want to first integrate the remote changes (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.`

Answer (score 0):

The local `origin/master` is not always the same as what is on the remote repository. In this case someone else has pushed code to master since the last time you pulled, so you have to pull those changes before pushing.

Comment: Then I geterror: You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).
hint: Please, commit your changes before merging.
fatal: Exiting because of unfinished merge.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by 1. pulling (git pull)
Then an error was shown because of merge conflicts
2. I exited it with (Q)
3. I took a look at (git status)
4. I removed the files shown as "changes to be committed: modified:" from the commit (git checkout path/file.csv
5. make the push as usual (git commit -m 'blabla', git push)